# TypeError: Object of type 'Add' is not JSON serializable - Python Graph

Tags: python, arrays, json, numpy, sympy

I am working on trying to create a tangent approximation of a function. However, trying to find a way to graph it on top of the graph. Both functions work, but when I graph the functions, I come up with the type error "Object of type 'Add' is not JSON serializable"

```
x = sp.Symbol("x")
y = sp.Symbol("y")
f = 1*(np.e**(-2*(((x**2 + y**2)**(1/2))-1))-2*np.e**(-1*(((x**2 + y**2)**(1/2))-1)))
fx = f.diff(x)
fy = f.diff(y)
x = np.linspace(-5,5,50)
y = np.linspace(-5,5,50)
[xx,yy] = np.meshgrid(x,y)
ff = 1*(np.e**(-2*(((xx**2 + yy**2)**(1/2))-1))-2*np.e**(-1*(((xx**2 + yy**2)** 
(1/2))-1)))
uu = f.subs(x,2).subs(y,2) + fx.subs(x,2).subs(y,2)*(xx) + fy.subs(x,2).subs(y,2)*(yy)


import plotly.graph_objects as go
fig = go.Figure(data=[go.Surface(x=xx,y=yy,z=uu),go.Surface(x=xx,y=yy,z=ff)])
fig.show()
```

The error occurs on the last line of code.

Comment: Examine your `uu` variable.  I suspect it is a `sympy` object (`Add`), not numeric (`numpy` array) as `ff` and `xx`, `yy` are.  I'm not familiar with `plotly`, but clearly it can't handle this `sympy` object.

Comment: You'll find a lot of SO answers/comments that warn against using `numpy` and `sympy` together.  You have the added complication of the `plotly`.

Comment: You are substituting an `np.linspace` object with 2 instead of a `sp.Symbol` object with 2. You either need to rename your linspace objects or move `uu` above your definitions of the linspace objects. I also strongly advise against using numpy functions in sympy expressions. Rather use `sp.exp(...)`. I also suggest doing `.evalf()` after the substitution so that all sympy object are removed before any further manipulation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is related to your coefficients (`f.subs(x,2).subs(y,2)`, `fx.subs(x,2).subs(y,2)`, and `fy.subs(x,2).subs(y,2)`). The coefficients are of type `<class 'sympy.core.numbers.Float'>`, which is not compatible for computations with numpy arrays. You can convert the coefficients using the `float()` command.